# VSCode Web auxiliary windows - how are they done

Tags: visual-studio-code

The new VSCode Web supports auxiliary windows same as VSCode does.

I wanted to know, how are they done? When I look at the source code of the auxiliary window, there seems to be no scripts loaded in that browser window. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code you're looking for is in [`src/vs/workbench/services/auxiliaryWindow/browser/auxiliaryWindowService.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/services/auxiliaryWindow/browser/auxiliaryWindowService.ts), and the corresponding code for the non-browser implementation is in [`src/vs/workbench/services/auxiliaryWindow/electron-sandbox/auxiliaryWindowService.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/services/auxiliaryWindow/electron-sandbox/auxiliaryWindowService.ts). The non-browser implementation does reuse some code from the browser implementation (`NativeAuxiliaryWindow` extends `AuxiliaryWindow`, and `NativeAuxiliaryWindowService` extends `BrowserAuxiliaryWindowService`, but the inheriting classes override some things that would otherwise be inherited, Ex. `createAuxiliaryWindow`). There's nothing I find very surprising. The browser service's `openWindow` implementation creates a new browser window at `about:blank` and then populates it using the `AuxiliaryWindow` constructor. `AuxiliaryWindow` extends `BaseWindow` from [`src/vs/workbench/browser/window.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/browser/window.ts).

Comment: Yeah, found it already. I thought how the Dom Nodes are transfered, but it's easily done via adoptNode on the window.